# How to install "rubygems"

Tags: ruby

I have been trying to install rubygems by using the command `gem install rubygems` in the command prompt but I keep getting the following errors:

```
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'rubygems' (>= 0) in any repository
ERROR:  Possible alternatives: ruby_gem, ruby_gs, rubyless, rubyjams, rubygene
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please don't apologize for being new to a language; We don't care about experience, we just want well asked questions. Please see "[ask]", "[Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648)" and all their linked pages. I also recommend the [Stack Overflow tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are trying to use RubyGems to install RubyGems.

The `gem`  command is powered by the RubyGems-gem. Since you can use it, it appears you already have it installed on your system.

In case you want to update use: `gem update --system`.

If you currently have RubyGems 1.1 or 1.2 on your system, please see "[Download RubyGems](https://rubygems.org/pages/download)" which recommends these commands:

```
gem install rubygems-update
update_rubygems
```